# Redraw buttons after rotation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, rotation

i draw some buttons dynamically on my UIView. I decide frames according to some mathematical computations and i want to redraw the screen when the device rotated. I registered my code for rotation notifications and `didRotate:` delegate method works properly. How can i redraw the screen when rotated?
**Some more explanation:**  I draw two columns of buttons if the rotation mode is Portrait, and i want to draw four columns when rotated to Landscape.. The button data is dynamic and comes from my HTTP server(count of buttons ect)

Comment: Are you drawing your buttons in the view's drawRect?  (If so, you can call setNeedsDisplay in your didRotate: and then check orientation in drawRect.)

Comment: @PhillipMills no i draw in a different method. but i can draw there too, don't i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use "willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation" method that allow you controlling your view if you rotate the device. 
This is some simple code that gives you an idea to make things works:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

// if you are in portrait mode
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    [yourOutletName setFrame:CGRectMake(255, 6, 25, 25)];
} 
// if you are in landscape mode
else
{
    [yourOutletName setFrame:CGRectMake(415, 6, 25, 25)];
}
}
```

Comment: thanks i tried this but download the data in a block, i need to call bloxk efficently. thanks for answer